# Bug in swift 2.0 NSDateFormatter?

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

NSDateFormatter doesn't seem to like October Eighteenth. Tried every other date with success. (???)

It is almost certainly a bug in swift 2.0 (and if it is what should I do? I need to submit my app really soon). Am I missing something?

Checked it in playground on Xcode 7.0.1:

```
let str = "2015-10-18"
let str2 = "2015-10-14"

let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

var date = formatter.dateFromString(str)
var date2 = formatter.dateFromString(str2)
```

Output:

```
"2015-10-18"
"2015-10-14"

<NSDateFormatter: 0x7f8aa050b760>
<NSDateFormatter: 0x7f8aa050b760>
<NSDateFormatter: 0x7f8aa050b760>

nil
"Oct 14, 2015, 12:00 AM"
```

Comment: It's certainly *not* a bug in Swift 2 since I just used your code [without errors](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOxUu3wld7hOmJRbAZ-5Gril9A9Jp_FMbyc). :)

Comment: @EricD. that's odd. I have same error. Which XCode version are you using?

Comment: @Caio Xcode 7 GM. Also works in Xcode 7.1 beta.

Comment: What timezone are you using? `America/Campo_Grande`, `America/Cuiaba`, and `America/Sao_Paulo` returns `nil`

Comment: I don't know why, but it's related to ours Daylight Saving Time date (We both have same default Time Zone). If you use the 2016 initial DST date ("2016-10-16") you will have the same issue.

Comment: You need to specify the calendar. Probably a bug

Comment: Thank you Leo Dabus!! You got it. As I don't specify the hour, it assumes it's midnight, but as it's daylight first day, there's no midnight, jumps straight to 1AM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior depends on which `timeZone` the formatter using.

For example: `America/Sao_Paulo`

In Sao Paulo, http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil/sao-paulo?year=2015

> Sunday, 18 October 2015, 00:00:00 clocks are turned forward 1 hour to
>   Sunday, 18 October 2015, 01:00:00 local daylight time instead

That means, there is no `2015-10-18 00:00:00` in Sao Paulo.

And as for `NSDateFormatter`, when it receives no *time* information from string, it assumes the time is `00:00:00` in its timezone. That's why it returns `nil`.

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "America/Sao_Paulo")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

formatter.dateFromString("2015-10-18 00:00") // -> nil
formatter.dateFromString("2015-10-18 00:30") // -> nil
formatter.dateFromString("2015-10-18 01:00") // -> non nil
```

---

As @LeoDabus stated, when you specify `.calendar` on the formatter:

> <s>it assumes the time is `00:00:00` in its timezone.</s>
>
> it will assume the start of the day for that date.

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "America/Sao_Paulo")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
formatter.calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)

formatter.dateFromString("2015-10-17") // -> Oct 17, 2015, 12:00 AM
formatter.dateFromString("2015-10-18") // -> Oct 18, 2015, 1:00 AM
formatter.dateFromString("2015-10-19") // -> Oct 19, 2015, 12:00 AM
```

Comment: This behavior actually depends if you specify a calendar or not. If you do it will assume the start of the day for that date for a specific locale. In that case 1am so there is no need to specify the time.

Comment: HI Leo, I had same problem using Objective-C, could you help  me with Objective-C similar code ?